# What does で do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

> 金銭のことで彼と争いになった。

Can someone explain what で does in this sentence? I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 「で」 expresses the ***cause or reason*** for an action or situation.

> "I got into a fight with him ***because of*** money matters."

「で」 is amazing and so is 「に」 and so is 「も」 and....  Without particles, life has no meanings.

Answer (score 0):

で (de) usually means "at" in English...kind of..

Think of "at" meaning the same as "because" like:
"The answer to your problem is (AT) this cause."
"We found what was (AT) the root of the problem."
etc.

ato de = later. Not in a different place, but AT a different time or situation.
(Unless you consider time a fourth directional dimension, but that's another forum!)

で can also mean "in".
"in this situation" instead of "at this situation"

"in this case", or "in the case or", or "because of"
special case-de,    situation-de.

The same with "I'm at the pool", "I'm in the pool".. or movie theater, etc.