# で particle: what is the role of it in this sentence?

Tags: particle-で

> 犠牲者や建物への大きな被害はないが、これまでの地震と大雪の害に続く今回の地震**で**、困難な状況が続いている。

could it mean "because of"? I know that で means "in", but I don't know if it can be used in this sentence.

what are the other meaning of で apart from "in" and "with"?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30879/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11357/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does で do in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/what-does-%e3%81%a7-do-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can mean "because" or refer to a cause. when it only follows a noun.

For example:

> 出張**で**アメリカへ行きました
>
> 仕事**で**C++を勉強しました

but you also can use te-form, it also can be a cause.

> 天気が悪**くて**、富士山が見えません。
>
> 新聞を読**んで**、国際の状況がすっかりわかりました。

---

te-form also be used in **order of verbs** to declear what's the first thing you did, what's the  second thing you did.

> 朝飯を食**べて**会社へ行きました。
>
> 買い物を**して**、家へ帰りました。

---

You also can use te-form to give a order, and command people to do what you want.

> もうちょっと急い**で**
>
> ちゃんと話を聞い**て**

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the particle で in this sentence has the meaning because of/due to/from/by (depending on context)

"...because this earthquake came after other earthquakes and heavy snows,..."

if you do a search on this site for "particle で"  you will get dozens of entries, many of them dealing with で vs. に, but if you search through you will find other grammar constructions using で as well.